# Bloomberg Security Lookup - Best way to lookup by symbol and exchange/country

Tags: api, bloomberg

What is the best way to lookup symbols based upon country or exchange? Example if I want to query for the March 2016 Ten Year Treasury Note I pass in 'TYH6 Comdty'. What if I want to designate the country or exchange in the query? Is that possible?

I'm trying to match position records from our clearing firm to calculate P&L with data from the Bloomberg API. I'm not sure if it's going to be a viable solution based upon clearing symbols and matching them to Bloomberg symbols for derivatives. I can match on Maturity(YYYYMM) but I'm not sure the product code will match up.

```
Request request = refDataService.CreateRequest("ReferenceDataRequest");
Element securities = request.GetElement("securities");
securities.AppendValue("TYH6 Comdty");
```

If I want to be able to filter the request by exchange or country, is that possible?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear - can you give an example of input and desired output? Also, have you asked HELP HELP?

Comment: @assylias I edited my original question to hopefully clear things up.